# XAMPP/Apache won't launch on port 81

Tags: apache, xampp

I just installed the latest XAMPP and I changed `httpd.conf` so it listens on port 81 (because Skype listens on 80):

```
Listen 81
```

However when I use the XAMPP CP to launch Apache, it says:

> Apache started [Port 80]

and then fails. If I stop Skype it says the same thing but doesn't fail and Apache listens on port 81, so my Apache config must be correct.

Why is XAMPP still checking port 80 and how do I stop it? I am running Windows 64-bit. XAMPP is installed in `C:\xampp`

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port/21914920#21914920

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution from XAMPP support so I'm answering my own question:

The solution was to change the port number in the sample XAMPP.INI file provided, then copy it to the xampp root dir.

Answer (score 0):

There is another line further down in the .conf file that also needs changing.

```
ServerName localhost:80
```

Now start Apache and MySQL, browse to http://localhost:81, and the contents of your htdocs folder should appear.

Regarding the message displayed in the xampp window, I would ignore it. Mine displays '[Port 80]' regardless of which port I have set it to use.

Comment: Yeah "[Port 80]" is just an echo from a batch file in I remember correctly. It's not intelligent at all.

Comment: Thanks but I forgot to mention I already changed that line, too. I've posted the solution that worked, below.