# How to change XAMPP apache server port?

Tags: apache, xampp

This is my Apache httpd.conf settings :

```
Listen 8012
ServerName localhost:8012
```

Every time I start Apache via `XAMPP` I see this message:

```
Status Check OK
Busy…
Apache Started [Port 80]
```

Anybody, please help me can I change any other settings ?

Comment: follow this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882121/busy-apache-started-port-80/8586632#8586632 You might find it useful.

Answer (score 416, accepted):

## To answer the original question:

To change the XAMPP [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) server port here the procedure :

### 1. Choose a free port number

The default port used by Apache is `80`.

Take a look to **all your used ports** with [Netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) (integrated to [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) Control Panel).

[image: Screenshot of xampp control netstat]

Then you can see all used ports and here we see that the `80`port **is already used** by `System`.

[image: screenshot netstat port 80]

Choose a free port number (`8012`, for this exemple).

### 2. Edit the file "`httpd.conf`"

> This file should be found in `C:\xampp\apache\conf` on *Windows* or in `bin/apache` for *Linux*.:

```
Listen 80
ServerName localhost:80
```

Replace them by:

```
Listen 8012
ServerName localhost:8012
```

Save the file.

Access to : http://localhost:8012 for check if it's work.

If not, you must to edit the `http-ssl.conf` file as explain in *step 3* below. ↓

### 3. Edit the file "`http-ssl.conf`"

> This file should be found in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra` on *Windows* or see this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/174897/possible-locations-of-ssl-conf-and-httpd-conf) for *Linux*.

Locate the following lines:

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerName localhost:443
```

Replace them by with a other port number (`8013` for this example) :

```
Listen 8013
<VirtualHost _default_:8013>
ServerName localhost:8013
```

Save the file.

Restart the Apache Server.

Access to : http://localhost:8012 for check if it's work.

### 4. Configure XAMPP Apache server settings

If your want to access localhost without specify the port number in the URL
 http://localhost instead of http://localhost:8012.

- Open **Xampp Control Panel**
- Go to **Config** ► **Service and Port Settings** ► **Apache**
- Replace the **Main Port** and **SSL Port** values ​​with those chosen (e.g. `8012` and `8013`).
- Save **Service settings**
- Save **Configuration of Control Panel**
- Restart the Apache Server
  [image: xampp apache setting port]
  It should work now.

#### 4.1. Web browser configuration

If this configuration isn't hiding port number in URL it's because your web browser is not configured for. See : **Tools ► Options ► General ► Connection Settings...** will allow you to choose different ports or change proxy settings.

#### 4.2. For the rare cases of ultimate bad luck

If step 4 and Web browser configuration are not working for you the only way to do this is to change back to 80, or to install a listener on port 80 (like a proxy) that redirects all your traffic to port 8012.

## To answer your problem :

If you still have this message in Control Panel Console :

> Apache Started [Port 80]

- Find location of `xampp-control.exe` file (probably in `C:\xampp`)
- Create a file `XAMPP.INI` in that directory (so `XAMPP.ini` and `xampp-control.exe` are in the same directory)

Put following lines in the `XAMPP.INI` file:

```
[PORTS]
apache = 8012
```

Now , you will always get:

> Apache started [Port 8012]

Please note that, **this is for display purpose only**. 
It has no relation with your `httpd.conf`.

Comment: awesome! That's work as a permanent solution, other ways to (considering a temporal and maybe nasty way) is ending the process that are using those ports.

Comment: but after try 4th step, it won't work as expected because iis will show insted of xampp. Is there any step I miss?

Comment: I followed step 4 but I still cannot access localhost without port. Could anyone please suggest something?

Comment: Is any update in step 4 I tried but not work, still need to include port

Comment: I've edit my answer for step 4 not working (add 4.1 and 4.2)

Comment: Why do you use 4**3**3 instead of 4**4**3 in 3. Edit the file "http-ssl.conf" (is this a typo?)

Comment: @PeterCo Yes it was a typo. I fix it. Thanks for your 2ct

Comment: the main error I did was me didnt look at dialog panel where there is ports column. It shows actually acting ports. I should just stop apache and run it again . And  shouldnt shut down whole xamp to relaunch.No.  Just stop and start within  that panel.Only then I saw the port was actually changed.

Answer (score 40):

The best solution is to reconfigure the XAMPP Apache server to listen and use different port numbers. Here is how you do it:

1) First, you need to open the Apache “httpd.conf” file and configure it to use/listen on a new port no. To open httpd.conf file, click the “Config” button next to Apache “Start” and “Admin” buttons. In the popup menu that opens, click and open httpd.conf

2) Within the httpd.conf file search for “listen”. You’ll find two rows with something like:

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

Change the port no to a port no. of your choice (e.g. port 1234) like below

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:1234
Listen 1234
```

3) Next, in the same httpd.conf file look for “ServerName localhost:” Set it to the new port no.

```
ServerName localhost:1234
```

4) Save and close the httpd.conf file.

5) Now click the Apache config button again and open the “httpd-ssl.conf” file.

6) In the httpd-ssl.conf file, look for “Listen” again. You may find:

```
Listen 443
```

Change it to listen on a new port no of your choice. Say like:

```
Listen 1443
```

7) In the same httpd-ssl.conf file find another line that says `<VirtualHost _default_:443>`. Change this to your new port no. (like 1443)

8) Also in the same httpd-ssl.conf you can find another line defining the port no. For that look for “ServerName”. you might find something like:

```
ServerName www.example.com:443 or  ServerName localhost:433
```

Change this ServerName to your new port no.

8) Save and close the httpd-ssl.conf file.

9) Finally, there’s just one more place you should change the port no. For that, click and open the “Config” button of your XAMPP Control Panel. Then click the, “Service and Port Settings” button. Within it, click the “Apache” tab and enter and save the new port nos in the “main port” and “SSL port” boxes. Click save and close the config boxes.

That should do the trick. Now “Start” Apache and if everything goes well, your Apache server should start up.

You will also see the Apache Port/s no in the XAMPP control panel has change to the new port IDs you set.

Comment: Not worked for me in macOS

Answer (score 4):

If the `XAMPP server` is running for the moment, stop XAMPP server.

**Follow these steps to change the port number.**

Open the file in following location.

```
[XAMPP Installation Folder]/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

Open the `httpd.conf` file and search for the String:

**Listen 80**

This is the port number used by XAMMP.

Then search for the string **ServerName** and update the **Port Number** which you entered earlier for `Listen`

***Now save and re-start XAMPP server.***

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to access your page by typing "**http://localhost:8012**" (after restarting the apache)?

Comment: Yes its working in localhost:8012 but when i trying remotely with my ip address http://my-ip-address:8012 getting page not found error.

Comment: You need to make sure that you are using your public/router's IP when using a device that is not connected to the same network, and make sure your router knows to forward all requests for that port to the hosting device. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/823124/2463800) is a great response to a similar question that should explain how to do this.

I recommend using [NoIP](http://www.noip.com/) for a URL that will not change. Also, with NoIP you can directly forward to a specific port so you don't need to append the URL.

Answer (score 2):

I had problem too.
I switced Port but couldn't start on 8012.

Skype was involved becouse it had the same port - 80. And it couldn't let apache change it's port.

So just restart computer and Before turning on any other programs Open xampp **first** change port let's say from 80 to 8000 or 8012 on these lines in httpd.conf

```
Listen 80
ServerName localhost:80
```

Restart xampp, Start apache, check localhost.

Comment: Actually Skype port is dynamic, it can change the port if it is already occupied. Simpler solution is to exit Skype, and then start Apache, the start Skype again. This is one time operation and solves the problem.

Comment: Yes it solves problem. But to those who don't want each time to restart skype they can use this.

Answer (score 1):

if don't work above port id then change it.like 8082,8080
Restart xammp,Start apache server,Check it.It's now working.

Answer (score 0):

If its Ubuntu SYSTEM:
Go to
`cd /opt/lampp/etc/`

```
vim httpd.conf
```

Here you can change the Listen Port Number

If you want to change the SSL Port:

```
`vim /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` -> Change the SSL Listen port
```

and  `vim /opt/lampp/properties.ini`  -> Do the changes here as well