# Unable to change Apache port number in Xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, port

I just downloaded Xampp server [xampp-win32-1.8.2-0-VC9.zip](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#641) file for windows and tried to start the apache server. But the server failed to start with the following message:

```
XAMPP now starts as a console application.

Instead of pressing Control-C in this console window, please use xampp_stop.exe
to stop XAMPP, because it lets XAMPP end any current transactions and cleanup
gracefully.

(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:
80
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

So clearly the port number 80 is already occupied.

So I went to the apache/conf/httpd.conf file and found the line:

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80
```

And changed the second line above to

```
Listen 8010
```

So the server must now start at port number 8010.But its instead starting on https default port number 443 and again giving the same error:

```
XAMPP now starts as a console application.

Instead of pressing Control-C in this console window, please use xampp_stop.exe
to stop XAMPP, because it lets XAMPP end any current transactions and cleanup
gracefully.

(OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:
443
AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

So how should I make the server run at the port number of my choice and why is my approach not working. As far as I can remember, the approach used to work on earlier versions of xampp but is not working now.

Comment: See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port/21914920#21914920

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran setup_xampp.bat and edited the port number from the control panes using the config button of apache. Then I found this line `Listen 80` and change the port number to 81 by editing this line. This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 6):

This is the [link](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-the-apache-port-in-xampp) which helped me to change my port.

[image]

[image]

And this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DWZ6Ecjl6I) too.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that Skype blocks XAMPP from running apache. Just close skype, open the server, and reopen skype. That fixed the issue for me.

Comment: this helped for me too

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Xampp, open this file **httpd-ssl.conf** and search for this entry **Listen 443**, change it to ,say, **Listen 444**

Then restart apache.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the port from the `https-ssl.conf`. From control panel of xamp config and apache (`Httpd-ssl.conf`) change the port.

Comment: Did not work for me.Refer my answer for the solution which worked in my case.Although I thank you for your answer!! :)