# XAMPP localhost shows nothing in browser

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am using windows 7 32bit. I have installed XAMPP and it's installed successful. When I browse localhost, browser shows nothing. It's not even in the state of connecting.

I even tried `localhost/xampp` but the result is same. I don't have skype installed in my computer. What's the problem?

This is output from browser.
[image]

And this is output from `netstat`.
[image]

This is my XAMPP control panel.

[image]

Comment: check error/access logs.

Comment: Where to check it? Where is the location of the logs?

Comment: ...probably something like /logs folder in xmapp folder?  Did you look?  Only answer making much sense so far is snalkum's.  Check the logs.  Also just for grins try http://127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have another application running on port 80. You could try to change the port([Unable to change Apache port number in Xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897693/unable-to-change-apache-port-number-in-xampp)). And check in your xampp options and see if the apache service is running successfully  on selected port.

Comment: micmec, By accepting this answer you are saying something else was on port 80? Confused by that and what the update was about...

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really really sorry because I need some reputation to upload images :( . I have changed the port but it's still the same.

Comment: Could you help me please?

Comment: Then do these two things.  try `https://127.0.0.1` and then find all the logs under the xmapp folder -  PHP and Apaches and actually look at them. Hey, turn off FileZilla while you are at it.

Comment: @snalkum : Sorry for the late reply. What page source do u mean? The error log seems to be fine. I don't have htaccess file on htdocs.

Comment: @ficuscr : Sorry for the late reply. Doing `https://127.0.0.1` works! But it needs to get through untrusted connection first and I have to make some certificate. Why is it? Is it really okay? And where is the location of the logs for PHP?

Comment: I would like to hear @ficuscr opinion but I still think that you have a problem with the port, because https works on another port. About the certificate you can read more here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure).

Answer (score -1):

run (xampp control panel) from start menu, then start your apache

Comment: can you send a screenshot? of the browser and the xampp control panel?

Comment: Yes. I have sent it. Please check.