# Error starting up Apache services from Xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, port

After installing a new version of Xampp on my laptop, I got the following error:

**Error log from Control Panel:**

```
9:24:26 AM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
9:24:26 AM  [Apache]    Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
9:24:26 AM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
9:24:26 AM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
9:24:26 AM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
9:24:26 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
9:24:26 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
9:24:27 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
9:24:27 AM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
9:24:27 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
9:24:27 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
9:24:27 AM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
9:24:27 AM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
9:24:27 AM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
9:24:27 AM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

**Output of Netstat**

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8883           MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:12680          MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49158          MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    10.23.121.46:139       MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:4242         MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:60544        MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:80                MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:135               MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:445               MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8000              MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8883              MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49152             MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49153             MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49154             MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49155             MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:49158             MW70VRC49LC8OO:0       LISTENING
```

I even disabled the port 80,443 from **Skype > Options > Advanced > Connection > Untick option: Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections.** I know Skype and Xampp have conflicting issues with the ports, hence I was told to disable it from Skype.

Is there a configuration that I need to do before hand, because I have another laptop and I didn't have any problems installing and starting up the Apache module on that.

Would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: post the output of netstat -a | find /i "list"

Comment: Do I copy that and paste it in the Shell program? I'm kind of new to Xampp. Didn't fully explore its capabilities and such.

Comment: Yes, run it from a command shell.

Comment: @EugenRieck I have edited my question with the output. Please verify if that's the correct output that's suppose to come out.

Comment: OK, we are now now sure, that another Webserver is running on port 80. You need to remove it or move Apache to an alternative port. Since I get this is a WAMP version upgrade, the "W" tells me to reboot and retry first.

Comment: Solution to your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port/21914920#21914920

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may have found a solution for it. As [@EugenRieck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100552/eugen-rieck) might have suggested for me to **change the port** due to the fact that the webserver is using port 80.

Hence, I edited the `Apache (httpd.conf)` file and changed the following line: `Listen 80` to another port number (eg. 82).