# Apache is not running from XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp, port

> I have IIS and skype like things on my system. So, i changed my port from 80 to 8081 and PID from 443 to 4433 or any other. And it was working after installation well and good. But then i restarted my system again. Apache didn't run and i tried to stop the ports and also changes my PORT and PID but it's still not working. Can anyone help me on this situation and i don't under all this now.

these are the [image: images]  I have done this too[image]

Comment: load apache FIRST and THEN open skype as they conflict sometimes on the same ports used

Comment: skype will use another port if the one it uses by default (e.g same as apache) is already taken

Comment: i have removed the option in skype to use port 80. but still it's not working

Comment: did you open apache FIRST and THEN skype?

Comment: i opened apache first.

Comment: Solution for your problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port/21914920#21914920

Answer (score 1):

I have installed xampp. but apache is not starting showing is program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-I1-1-0. dil is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this program