# xampp Apache won't start tried all

Tags: apache, xampp

in my Xampp Apache never start, so I try to change the port as all the suggestion. But even after that I get the same error message.

When I start Xampp I get his message

[image]

But I have change my port number `80` to `81` and when it does not work I have change it to `88` even and still it is the same result.
See the visual !

[image]
[image]

Anyone knows what I should do !

I am running it on Windows 8 !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21914920

Comment: @Sirko plz lookt at my question I have change the port !

Comment: you write you changed the http port, but the error also lists the https port (443) as being blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Skype or Teamviewer is running on your system? If yes, close all application and Try, Otherwise in worst case, Try to install it in some other drive than C: