# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, windows, xampp

All of a sudden my XAMPP crashed. I cannot start the MySQl service. I am being shown this error message.

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
12:36:03 PM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:36:03 PM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:36:03 PM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:36:03 PM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:36:03 PM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
12:36:03 PM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

Are there any ways to solve this problem? I also have checked my Skype its turned off.

Comment: try to chnage your port and run xampp and make sure you have any antivirus thos who block your port

Comment: how to change the port for the MySQL @MayankVadiya

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change XAMPP apache server port?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)

Comment: but thats for the Apache..

Comment: It's worth taking  a backup of your MySQL directory, if you have important data in there. Please check your logs as the error suggests - anything at the end there that might give clues?