# My Apache isn't starting, i'm using xampp

Tags: php, mysql, apache

[error stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1uHn.jpg)

```
1:09:28 PM [Apache] Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
1:09:28 PM [Apache] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
1:09:28 PM [Apache] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.  
1:09:28 PM [Apache] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check    
1:09:28 PM [Apache] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues  
1:09:28 PM [Apache] If you need more help, copy and post this  
1:09:28 PM [Apache] entire log window on the forums
```

Kindly check the error & let me know..

Comment: 1:09:28 PM  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
1:09:28 PM  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
1:09:28 PM  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
1:09:28 PM  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
1:09:28 PM  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
1:09:28 PM  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
1:09:28 PM  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

Answer (score 0):

What port are you using ? I know that in the previous version, skype was using the same port wich make xamp not starting.

Answer (score 0):

By default port number will be 80.

if you are using Skype in your machine it will show error like this.

you need to change some configurations.

Those all you can find here -  [How to change XAMPP apache server port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)

Answer (score 0):

Open Skype.

```
Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection.
```

Disable:

```
"Use port 80 and 443 for alternatives for incoming connections"
```

Sign Out and Close all Skype windows. Try restarting your Apache.