# XAMPP 1.7.7 - Apache won't start (ports already changed)

Tags: apache, xampp, port

I installed XAMPP 1.7.7 for testing on the old php version. Current XAMPP is running fine. I changed the ports in httpd.conf from 80 to 8081, and in httpd-ssl.conf from 443 to 4434.

Still, when trying to start apache, I get the error

```
"error: apache was stopped unexpected. This might be caused by a blocked port, missing dependencies,..."
```

I also changed these ports again (they were not used in both cases).

I run XAMPP as an administrator and I disabled my firewall without any results... What are other possible options? (Error-)Logs are empty.

maybe the following information might help:
I am using windows 10, xampp 1.7.7 portable, and although I changed the ports, when I run XAMPP, it tells me the following:

```
Problem detected!
Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" (PID 4)!
Apache will NOT start without the configured ports free!
```

Comment: See this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port/21914920#21914920

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

Run -> CMD, type services.msc and stop the program:
Web Deployment Agent Service

Afterwards try restarting XAMPP and say if it works or not!

Comment: I don't have a service named "web deployment agent service" installed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it via reinstalling into another directory.