# Running Pow & XAMPP Simultaneously

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xampp, rack-pow

I have a machine with XAMPP installed and running and I need to install POW to work in a ruby project.

Anyone have any luck running both XAMPP and Pow?

- http://pow.cx/manual.html
- https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html

Comment: Perhaps it would help to explain what happens when you try to run both of these at the same time. Presumably, since you're asking this question, it doesn't work. But in what way does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind two servers on Port 80 (default of XAMPP apache & default of pow).

You can change the port of the Apache like this: [How to change XAMPP apache server port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)