# port 80:installing apache for php as well as for java

Tags: java, php, apache, xampp, port80

I have installed Apache tomcat 4.0 and I have run server side code in java using port 8080 (or 80 ).

I want to program in php and run on Apache but php also uses port 80.

Will it give me any problems if I use them at the same time or separately?

I have not installed xampp .

EDIT:I have windows as OS and created an Ubuntu virtual machine using Vmware.

Comment: go ahead try it , come up with an actual problem  plus port addresses can be changed right

Comment: you can change port for Apache. If any other services using port 80 then defiantly it raise issue. Either stop all other services and then run Apache, or change the port permanently.  Check here:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/21914920/4248328

Comment: can i install apache in ubuntu using vmware and then use it for php? will it resolve the issue?@Anant

Comment: you can install LAMP in ubuntu and for that you have to check some other liknks. The above is for xampp . check for ubuntu:- http://askubuntu.com/questions/342132/how-to-give-specific-port-to-apache-in-ubuntu-12-04-and-port-for-mysql

Comment: @AakritiGupta welcome :):)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used PHP in some time, but I don't remember it ever using a port.  The server software it runs on (in your case APACHE - either using the PHP CGI connector or the Apache shared library).  You need to chnge your port in APACHE - read the Apache docs on the subject here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen