# Installing apache2 from another machine via ssh

Tags: apache2

My friend installed an apache2 in my computer from his computer. When I look at the net-stat of my machine for apache2, it shows the following information in the picture. How can I make my machine listen to port 80? Is it appropriate to install apache2 this way? I am new to this, please suggest me what does the information in the picture carry any security issue with this? 
Thank you

[image]

Comment: is this win*** netstat? looks like alot port open! show httpd.conf! to check what is your apache listen to?

Comment: read `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port` hope fix your problem

Comment: This netstat is ubuntu netstat with apache2 installed to ubuntu 14.04.