# xampp apache server up and running, yet bad request

Tags: php, apache, iis, xampp, port

I got some trouble with my xampp on Win 10, as so many have had before me...
It's the same old port problem with skype and IIS.
I used to quit skype and stop the *world wide web publishing service*, but am sick of having to go through the whole ordial every time I start xampp.
so yesterday I changed the ports for my apache server and ecerything worked fine.
started up today and boom...localhost couldn't find my pages.
So I checked for port problems in xampp...there were none! apache was up and running(as were mysql server and filezilla). no error messages, nothing.

I resetted the ports to 80 and 443. killed of skype and the iis and everything worked fine again. Now whenever I change the ports, it will not run.
I did everything according to here:

[How to change XAMPP apache server port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port/21914920#21914920)

(I changed the ports in *httpd.conf*, *httpd-ssl.conf* and in *service and port settings* )

I just don't get it. why it won't run with changed ports(and yes I checked the ports for being empty).
atm I have changed the port 80 -> 8024 
and port 443 -> 1337 (no matter what I change this port to it always throws bad request)

8024 works fine. I can get to the dashboard via localhost:8024
but localhost:1337 gives me a bad request.

any suggestions, or similar encounters?
For now will have to continue using standart ports and kill of the 2 processes, but I really wanna skip that in the future.

I used port 80->8024 
and port 443->448 yesterday and it worked fine...really weird...

Comment: If you are not using IIS then its simpler to just uninstall it, SKYPE can be configured to NOT use 80 and 443 [check the docs for how to](https://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Disabled-checkbox-quot-Use-port-80-and-443-for-additional/td-p/4517969) Then leave Apache on its standard ports

Comment: already change skype ports, but it seems that the problem lies with the _world wide web publishing service_ from win10.
also just reinstalled xampp, thought maybe some files got corrupted, but didn't change anything. left apache on it's standard ports for now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so that means your system has Microsoft IIS installed or one of the other bits of MS technology that reports that signature, they are doing that on later versions of Windows for some reason.

If you are not intending to use it you can uninstall it, it is not an integral part of windows so its being uninstalled wont effect normal operations of windows, and if you need to install it again later, it comes as part of the standard OS so you wont need to do anything perticularly clever.

So go to `Start -> Control Panel -> Programs and Features`

Click the 'Turn windows features on and off' link in the left hand menu.
Wait for the list to load and then find 'Internet Information Services'

Un check the check boxes for the following items ( you may not see all of them ), and there may be others I done know about. You may have all of these or just some of these.

1. IIS
2. Web Deploy 2.0 (Web Deployment Agent Service)
3. MS Sql Server Reporting service.
4. BranchCache ( Windows 8.1 )
5. SQL Server VSS Writer

[List of possible service names](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fort_sql/archive/2010/05/31/list-of-sql-server-service-names.aspx) not sure how up to date this is.
[Tutorial on how to find what ports are in use on your system and what app is using them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bgroth/archive/2004/11/11/256190.aspx)

Windows will then have a think for a while and then remove those applications, you will probably be asked to reboot to complete the uninstalls.
Reboot anyway when the uninstalls are complete.

Then try XAMPP again

Comment: thy for your answer.
however only 2 boxes are checked under _Internet Information Services_
first one being _Internet Information services_ -> _World Wide Web Services_ -> _Application Developement Features_ -> _.NET extensibility 4.6_ and the other one being _Internet Information services_ -> _World Wide Web Services_ -> _Security_ -> _Request Filtering_
I have however managed to get everything running, without having to manually close down the w3svc. I changed it do be automatically started with a delay. for now it seems to work...let's keep fingers crossed...