# my project is not opening after changing ports of apache server successfully. i am able to access admin panel using new port num

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

my project is not opening after changing ports of Apache server successfully. 
I am able to access admin panel using new port num localhost:8012/phpmyadmin.

I am working in xampp server. 
yesterday I have installed sql server due to class project. 
I have changed ports of xampp Apache listen:8012 and ssl port to 1443. 
I can open admin panel using the link localhost:8012/phpmyadmin this is giving me my panel but when I tried to open my project using link localhost:8012/health-care/ (instead of localhost/health-care/ that was working perfectly) now my index login page is opening without any css image etc. and after entering information no other page is working.

after changing server name in database configuation in codeigniter form localhost to localhost and asset url in constants to `define('ASSET_URL', "http://localhost:8012/health-care/assets/");` only index page is loading but not others

please help to solve this problem. I can't lose my work. please help

Comment: see this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port

Comment: i have changed my port numbers using this answer with votes 22

Comment: What kind of application you are using for your project? Maybe you have to change the application URL to 'localhost:8012/health-care/' in the database/configuration.

Comment: i have followed the whole procedure written on your suggested page but its working for changing ports not for running projects like before

Comment: i am using codeigniter framework and its an web app. before installing sql server my project was in working position. i have placed my health-care folder in htdocs and it was fine but now its not working at all

Comment: thanks RoseHosting for giving me such a wonderful solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved.

just change three line first in config.php remaining two lines in constants.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/health-care/';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8012/health-care/';
```

and second one from:

```
define('ASSET_URL', "http://localhost/health-care/assets/");
```

to:

```
define('ASSET_URL', "http://localhost:8012/health-care/assets/");
```

last image directory from:

```
$images_base_path = "http://localhost/health-care/system_data/images/";
```

to:

```
$images_base_path = "http://localhost:8012/health-care/system_data/images/";
```

and its done. thanks RoseHosting for giving me idea