# Object not found after changing ports from 80 to 8080

Tags: xampp

I've just changed my apache ports from 443 and 80 to 4433 and 8080 and now when trying to get access to my websites via the url localhost:8080/mywebsites/ all fails and I get the message:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. 

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.30
```

Comment: Check for the code that has these ports hardcoded

Comment: Where is this code and what do I do to it?

Comment: See the accepted answer at this link, there is likely more config to do.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change XAMPP apache server port?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)