# Xamp Apache wont start. ( not a port issue , Xamp crashed )

Tags: windows, apache, crash, xampp

So i was working on some project on 'Xampp', and due to some issue windows froze , browser and 'Xampp', so i used Control+Alt+delete ( Task Manager)  killed explorer , opened again, restarted windows and opened 'Xampp', and then tried to start Apache again , but it wont start.  and please do not say try to change port , because i know port 80 is used by system , so i already use a different port. By the way , 'MySql' starts just fine.   only issue with Apache.  And i also uninstalled xamp , and reinstalled , but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It was indeed the port issue , but not the httpd.conf file rather  https-ssl-conf , changed from 443 to 444. and the reason i was able to find this problem was because , i started xamp in administrator mode. checked the service box for apache. then ran in normal mode. and below it showed the error message that 443 port is causing the issue. before it was just showing the general error message.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a very detail troubleshooting steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)
By default port :80 is use considering that no other application claims the port. If decide to adopt a different port, it better to used a higher port like :8080 to avoid port conflicts with well know ports.