# How to set xampp to connect to the port without adding it in the url

Tags: php, apache, port

So I changed my apache port for security issues, I changed it to port 8015, everything works normally, able to access with http://localhost:8015 and everything. I want to set xampp so that I don't need to write the port number in the url, how do I set so that by just using http://localhost to connect to port 8015 ?

I have changed through xampp control panel > config > service and port settings and changed the main port to 8015, restarted service, even restarted computer, still can't access port 8015 just using http://localhost, http://localhost:8015 still works though. What did I miss ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't possible, not just with XAMPP. HTTP listens on port 80 by default. When you say http://localhost:8015, you specify port 8015.

Comment: Oh okay then if it is impossible, I got the idea from this thread that makes it seems like it's possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port

Comment: @Charas have you tried following the instructions on the verified answer there?