# XAMPP apache cannot connect to listening port

Tags: windows, apache, http, web, xampp

I am using xampp on windows 10 and trying to get apache to work. I have set it to listen to port 50563 in the httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf, however when I run httpd.exe I get this message:

> (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:50563
>
> (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket    address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  :    AH00072:    make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:50563
>
> AH00451: no
> listening sockets available, shutting down
>
> AH00015: Unable to open
> logs

I have tried running as administrator, I check netstat and that port is free. What should I do?

httpd.conf: https://pastebin.com/NUrWBfRB
httpd-ssl.conf https://pastebin.com/YLLfzEjP

Comment: you still have the port 8080 configured for Apache. The answer for your question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port

Comment: sorry, I added the wrong error message, it is giving me the error message with the correct port 50563

Comment: what happens if you change to another port, like 50564?

Comment: I get the exact same error

Comment: Open a command prompt and try with `netstat -a -b` to find out if there is actually a program using that port.

Comment: no program is using that port, this happens on literally every port I try, regardless of whether it is listening or being used

Comment: What happens if you open a command promp as Admisnitrator and run `apache_start.bat` that comes with XAMPP?

Comment: it gives the exact same error

Comment: Please edit your answer and put your config files

Comment: added httpd.conf

Comment: Please correct the formatting

Comment: formatting is now correct

Comment: Can you post to a gist? or pastebin.com? I think that will be easier to follow because for example your Listen line is commented and that seems bad...

Comment: okay Ive linked httpd and httpd-ssl to pastebin

Comment: You pasted the same file twice.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are trying to listen on 50563 for both http and https? If this is the case you MUST use different ports, maybe **use 50563 and 50564** for HTTP and HTTPS respectively.

> In the case of multiple Listen directives, Apache will bind to port 80
>   the first time and then try to bind to port 80 a second time. This
>   yields a nice **"Could not bind to port"** error on start up. This
>   seems to happen with newbies and Debian based distros, where Debian
>   based distros have Listen 80 defined in ports.conf. Newbies don't
>   realize this and create another Listen 80 line in *.conf.

From: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CommonMisconfigurations

Comment: so Ive changed the http-ssl port to 50564 and the httpd config is listening for port 50563 but Im still getting the error for port 50563

Comment: Can you paste your conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf, conf/extra/httpd-default.conf and conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf too?

Comment: In the vhost file set the NameVirtualHost *:50563 and also check if there is other Listen 50563 directive in other file than the httpd.conf

Comment: I have set the name virtual host and checked for 50563 in other files, still get the same error :/

Comment: I recommend to uninstall XAMPP and install it again to start clean.., then see if you get Apache listening on 80 (default port) and then just change the Listen 80 line to 50563 on httpd.conf and restart apache.

Comment: ah, it's now working after re-instaling. No idea why it didnt work before :/ Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @james-clarke If this has helted to resolve the problem please mark the question as is. Thanks!