# Visual studio: unable to compile aspx page as unable to start iisexpress

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express, error-code

I'm new to visual studio so please help me out on this. I have search for similar questions but it didn't work or it is unanswered.

So I just created a .aspx page in visual studio 2017 and I wanted to compile it and show it on a web browser (I use chrome for it) but it gave an error:

[Visual studio Error generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlB1A.png):

```
Unable to start iisexpress.

The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
For more information about the error, run iisexpress.exe with the tracing switch enabled (/trace:error).
```

So long story short, I went on to cmd to trace issexpress error and got this:

[error I got from cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSqA5.png):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress.exe /trace:error
Starting IIS Express ...

Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 19870296

W3 Server initializing WinSock.  CTC = 19870312

W3 Server WinSock initialized.  CTC = 19870312

W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled).  CTC = 19870312

Start listenerChannel http:0

Error (rc=80070422) in UlInitialize. Exiting

Error initializing ULATQ.  hr = 80070422

Terminating W3_SERVER object

InitComplete event signalled

Process Model Shutdown called

Waiting for all LISTENER_CHANNELS to stop
```

---

There were people who said to uninstall and reinstall iisExpress, delete IISExpress folder in document and run IIS Express again. Those didn't work and many others were similar case but different error code.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Oh and not sure if it's related, I have on my IIS with these checked:
[windows features, IIS checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5rks.png)

Comment: Please copy the text of the error message and output from cmd to the body of your question; text in the body of a question is always preferable to any form of image. Feel free to include the image links anyway, but please include the messages here.

Comment: okay, edited it

Comment: Collect and include the diagnostics information in your question, or nobody would be able to assist, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the xamp port.Both Xamp and ASP.net working on the same port.If you change the xamp port, then it will work.please try and let me know.

[How to change XAMPP apache server port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel:

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features\Turn windows feature on or off\ => Enable IIS.

To Enable IIS:
Tick the IIS essential feature.Please find the below-mentioned image.
[IIS image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhIL6.jpg)

Comment: hi, i went to checked the box in windows feature for the ones shown in the image and also took a step further and used the visual studio repair to repair my VS in case it was the VS fault. Both didn't work. is there any other thing i need to check in IIS? not sure if it will affect, but i have xamp installed in my pc as well.

Comment: Please change the port no for your xamp. Both xamp and asp.net use the same port.I think that's why it's not working.Please check and let me know.