# apache webserver is already running in centos xampp

Tags: php, apache, centos, command, pid

I am trying to run xampp in centos and i have already installed it and all php modules. The only issue i face is while i want to start apache getting the below error.

Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.2.0-0... XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail. XAMPP: Another web server is already running. XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok. XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.

I have already tried stopping and starting apache and that did not work. 
Please let me know if there is a solution to this. I am using centos.

Comment: maybe show us the commands you used to run/stop/restart the server and some outputs

Answer (score 0):

You already have a server running in the background. The simplest way would be to change the port on which you start your XAMPP server.

Look at this for more information:
[How to change XAMPP apache server port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)