# Unable to configure xampp server on windows

Tags: apache, xampp

After I changed the [port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port), apache is not reaching running state 
.Before I was able to start mysql server from xampp control panel and it was running fine.

It is not triggering any error as well.
for better understanding see the screen shot [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpwYO.png)

what could be the issue here?

**recent logs in apache:**

```
  Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
  to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
  Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
  to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
  Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-info.conf
  to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-info.conf
  Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
  to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
  Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
  to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
  Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/httpd.conf
  to c:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf
  Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/magic
  to c:/Apache24/conf/magic
 Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/charset.conv
 to c:/Apache24/conf/charset.conv
 Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/proxy-html.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
 Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
 Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-dav.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf
 Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/mime.types
 to c:/Apache24/conf/mime.types
 Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-languages.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf
 Duplicated c:/Apache24/conf/original/extra/httpd-manual.conf
 to c:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf
```

Comment: have you checked the log-files. its located at `\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log`. can you update your question with the last entries of that log-file.

Comment: no such file logs in php

Comment: @wayneOS This is about the http server not starting, not about php.

Comment: Oh sorry copied the wrong line! check that logs `xampp\apache\logs`

Comment: updated with recent logs of apache

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. It looks like it is a port-issue. which port did you choose? are you sure it is free? have you checked with `netstat` in a cmd-window?

Comment: yes, it is free i checked it

Answer (score 0):

1. Revert the port. Does this fix the problem?
2. Determine where all your CONF files are. If you have duplicates, determine which duplicates are invalid.
3. If all else fails, consider uninstalling Apache ([link](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-uninstall-apache-in-windows)) and reinstall from XAMPP.