# Must type in port number with URL to connect to server

Tags: apache

I am trying to set up an apache server for a small local site. The problem I am having is you must enter the port number to reach the site.

Everything is installed through XAMPP. So far I have been able to access the site from mysite:8080/page.php, I would like to access it from mysite/page.php, as my users would likely have a tough time remembering to enter the port number every time. Any help on the issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change XAMPP apache server port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)

Comment: @David I do not believe so, my issue is that the port number is correct, however I just want to be able to type in the URL without having to add the port number in the address bar. I currently cannot access my site via mysite/page.php. I have to type mysite:8080/page.php. I am looking to eliminate the typing of the port number to access the page.

Comment: Currently your server listens on port 8080.  Your goal is for it to listen on port 80.  That involves changing the server port.  On the other hand, if 8080 is the port you want to use, then either users will have to enter that port number in the address or you'll need your routing hardware to forward incoming connections on port 80 to your server on port 8080.

Comment: what operating system are you using?

Comment: @David I have "Listen 8080" in the xampp\apache\conf file. I don't know if this is correct or not. I will try changing the server's port back to 80 and see what happens.

Comment: @DRBonn we are using server 2012R2.

Comment: @David you were correct. I am well beyond the depths of my knowledge here, tremendous thank you. Do you want to submit that as a solution and I can then mark as answer to help others in the future possibly? Again many thanks!