# Xampp installation difficulty

Tags: xampp

I keep on getting the following error message each time I try to install XAMPP on PC:

```
11:15:57 PM  [Apache]   Problem detected!
11:15:57 PM  [Apache]   Port 443 in use by ""C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\VisualSVNServer.exe" -k runservice -C "LoadModule log_visualsvn_module bin/mod_log_visualsvn.so" -E nul" with PID 8608!
11:15:57 PM  [Apache]   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:15:57 PM  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:15:57 PM  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Can someone help me please.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It says clearly what's wrong (Visual SVN sever is already using port 443) and how to fix it: stop Visual SVN server or pick another port for XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

If Xampp isn't installing due to the in-use port, you can open Task Manager, then go to the services tab, sort by PID and then find the PID as mentioned in the error message. Right-click on the matching service, then select stop from the context menu. Once the service is stopped, then try installing Xampp again.

If Xampp has installed, but won't start a server due to an in-use port, you can configure Xampp to use a different port. You can do so by following the instructs found here in the top answer on this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port).