# pages not loading completly using symfony 3.4 using localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php/PATH

Tags: symfony, phpstorm, symfony-3.4

As I munched pages do not fully load in some cases when I try to access them from

localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php/Path .

[**Image1** *localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php/Path*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OOfJ.png)

But every page load fine using just localhost:port/PATH .

[**Image2** *localhost:port/PATH*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59hHX.png)

**My /app/config/config.yml`**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@CalendrierMedecinsBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi: ~
    #translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    session:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }

sensio_framework_extra:
   router:
        annotations: false
```

**My /app/config/routing.yml**

```
    calendrier_medecins:
    resource: "@CalendrierMedecinsBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

**My /app/config/routing_dev.yml**

```
_wdt:
    resource: '@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml'
    prefix: /_wdt

_profiler:
    resource: '@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml'
    prefix: /_profiler

_errors:
    resource: '@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml'
    prefix: /_error

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

**routing.yml in my Bundle**

```
    calendrier_medecins_homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: CalendrierMedecinsBundle:Patient:addPatient }
calendrier_medecins_ajoutp:
    path:     /ajoutPatient
    defaults: { _controller: CalendrierMedecinsBundle:Patient:addPatient }


calendrier_medecins_affichep:
    path:     /affichePatient
    defaults: { _controller: CalendrierMedecinsBundle:Patient:getAllPatient }

calendrier_medecins_recherchepatient:
    path:     /recherchePatient
    defaults: { _controller: CalendrierMedecinsBundle:Patient:recherchepatient }
```

**Composer.json**

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" },
    "files": [ "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php" ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "symfony-scripts": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@symfony-scripts"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.6"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "3.4-dev"
    }
}}
```

**recherechePatient.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Table V01</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ asset('/madderahmed/images/icons/favicon.ico') }}"/>
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/madderahmed/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/madderahmed/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/madderahmed/vendor/animate/animate.css') }}">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/madderahmed/vendor/select2/select2.min.css') }}">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/madderahmed/vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css') }}">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/madderahmed/css/util.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/madderahmed/css/main.css') }}">
    <!--===============================================================================================-->

    <style>
        input[type=text], select {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>
</head>
{% block body %}
<body>





<div class="limiter">

    <div class="container-table100">

        <div class="wrap-table100">

            <div class="table100">

                <form style="position: absolute; margin-top: -200px;" method="post" >
                    <div ><span ><i ></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input  placeholder="Nom" type="text" name="nom">
                    <div ><span ><i></i></span>
                        <input placeholder="Prenom" type="text" name="prenom">
                    </div>
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="recherche">


                </form>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                    <tr class="table100-head">
                        <th class="column1">ID</th>
                        <th class="column2">Nom</th>
                        <th class="column3">Prénom</th>
                        <th class="column4">Date</th>
                        <th class="column5">Heure</th>
                        <th class="column6">Medecin</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for p in patient %}
                    <tr>
                        <td class="column1">{{ p.id }}</td>
                        <td class="column2">{{ p.nom }}</td>
                        <td class="column3">{{ p.prenom }} </td>
                        <td class="column4">{{ p.date|date("m/d/Y") }}</td>
                        <td class="column5">{{ p.heure }}</td>
                        <td class="column6">{{ p.medecin }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<!--===============================================================================================-->
<script src="{{ asset('/madderahmed/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('/madderahmed/js/main.js') }}"></script>

</body>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

[Web-folder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGAei.png)

Comment: It's not a link with Symfony, what is your OS ? How are you run symfony in your local ?

Comment: @Gary i'm on **Windows 10** and using **XAMPP**

Comment: Ok good, what you use for front-end ? Twig only ? Webpack maybe ?

Comment: I use Twig @Gary

Comment: the first indicator can you tell me if you use 80 like a default port apache into your xxamp : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port

Comment: yes, my default port apache is 80 in xampp  @GaryHoubre

Comment: Oh ok, can you show in your question, your composer.json please.

Comment: I have  added  **composer.json** at the bottom mr @Gary I just want to let you know that some pages work fine with *localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php/Path*
but someothers don't and only work with *localhost:port/PATH*

Comment: Oh i see... can you share your base.html.twig, where have you include your css file ?

Comment: you need a configure a vhost ( like a url, example : project.dev/path ). https://ultimatefosters.com/hosting/setup-a-virtual-host-in-windows-with-xampp-server/

Comment: I have added my twig page mr @Gary

Comment: I think, if you don't configure a vhost, you have got a problem. look a comment before this.