# iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0) after installing XAMPP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, xampp

After installing `XAMPP` , `IIS` is not starting.

I got the following error when trying to start the `.net` `mvc` application through `visual-studio` 2019.

> The program '[1416] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

IIS was working in port 53366 and XAMPP is working in port 80.

I tried the following with no luck:

- Change XAMPP port using: [How to change XAMPP apache server port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)
- Change the port number (and virtual directory)
- Deleting the .vs folder
- Use 64-bit of version of IISexpress
- Restart the computer

I also tried `iisexpress.exe /trace:error` getting the following:

> ```
> Starting IIS Express ...
> Initializing the W3 Server Started CTC = 3635593
> W3 Server initializing WinSock.  CTC = 3635593
> W3 Server WinSock initialized.  CTC = 3635593
> W3 Server ThreadPool initialized (ipm has signalled).  CTC = 3635593
> Start listenerChannel http:0
> Error (rc=80070422) in UlInitialize. Exiting
> Error initializing ULATQ.  hr = 80070422
> Terminating W3_SERVER object
> InitComplete event signalled
> Process Model Shutdown called
> Unable to start iisexpress.
>
> The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.
> For more information about the error, run iisexpress.exe with the tracing switch enabled (/trace:error).
> ```

Comment: The existence of such posts, https://forums.iis.net/t/1232737.aspx indicates that you fell into a rabbit hole of uncertainty. Try to use different virtual machines for different web server stacks so as to keep the environment clean and easy to manage. Conflicts are everywhere and the vendors do not usually test complex setup.

Comment: I found a similar question on MSDN, you can refer to it: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9cbe05df-36df-4005-857f-d08ac82492b3/the-program-14400-iisexpressexe-has-exited-with-code-0-0x0?forum=visualstudiogeneral