# How to find empty port on windows to to run xampp?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localserver

So I usually code in python. And for some academic reasons, I am trying PHP. To run I need an apache server. And apparently, I cannot run xampp properly no matter how much I change port. So I would like it if you had the same problem and could please help me.

-Thank you very much for helping! (Or at least giving your time!)

Comment: you can try to use port 8080 read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port

Comment: It is probably best if you tell us your issues, then we can help fix them rather than assuming a port change will solve all your problems

Comment: XAMPP uses 2 ports, one for Apache and one for MariaDB. Which one do you believe you are having issues with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find available ports through command prompt, ran as administrator. Simple use : netstat -ab