# Xampp port 80 is use

Tags: php, xampp

Port 80 in use by ""C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice" with PID 30352!
Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Edit : I've tried all solutions I found in StackOverflow but it doesn't work!!

Comment: You have apache serving on port 80 already as a separate program from xampp. If you want to use the xampp version you can turn off your current apache instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the control panel, change the port to another port not being used

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port

Answer (score 0):

You have apache serving on port 80 already as a separate program which is not xampp. This seems to be Apache24 based on your file path. If you want to use the xampp version you can turn off your current apache instance. If you know that you want this alternative apache to be turned off, you can kill it with the command below from CMD.

TASKKILL /F /IM httpd.exe /T

Once it's gone, you can turn on xampp's apache and it will bind to port 80 by default.

Comment: ERROR: The process with PID 10132 (child process of PID 4528) could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.
ERROR: The process with PID 4528 (child process of PID 660) could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.

Comment: Are you the owner of this computer? If so, you can change the name of the apache24 file and then restart your pc to stop apache from running

Comment: Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
5:38:30 PM  [mysql]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
5:38:30 PM  [mysql]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
5:38:30 PM  [mysql]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
5:38:30 PM  [mysql]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
5:38:30 PM  [mysql]  If you need more help, copy and post this
5:38:30 PM  [mysql]  entire log window on the forums