# How to resolve service problem in xampp with Apache?

Tags: apache, xampp

Whenever I click on apache service to start in xampp server it gives me error.
Please help me out.
[XAMPP control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNI2J.png)

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask]. Another important step: Please search for the error message(s) before asking here and let us know what you have tried so far from the numerous solutions that you can easily find everywhere. This is a very common problem that can easily be found through the search engine of your least distrust.

Answer (score 0):

Without a proper log, I cannot tell you the exact problem. Most probably your port 80 is using by other service

Considering port blocked, you have two available options

1. stop the service which is using port 80

run cmd as administrator and run below command. It will ask you whether you want to run this, give Y

```
 net stop http
```

2. change port 80 in Apache
   [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)

Comment: thank you this helped me out. Port 80 was blocked and shift to port 8080 and worked.

Comment: @maria can you mark as accepted answer and as useful answer. Thanks a lot